# Prove that in every digraph $D$, some strong component has no entering edges and some strong component has no exiting edges.

Tags: graph-theory

I've been trying to prove the following result in "Introduction to Graph Theory (2'nd edition) by Douglas B. West":

> Prove that in every digraph $D$, some strong component has no entering edges and some strong component has no exiting edges.

Why is this true ?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: if every component had exiting edges you can create an infinite sequence of strong components $D_1\to D_2\to\ldots$. Since there are only a finite number of those components there must be a repetition. What does this mean?

Comment: Aha, this implies that there must be some $D_i$ repeating in the list which create a larger strong component consisting of every component between the two $D_i$ repeating because of a cycle. Thus there exist only one strong component or there must be some component that has no exiting edges.

Comment: "Thus there exist only one strong component or there must be some component that has no exiting edges." You can jus conclude: there must be a component that has no exiting edges. If there is only one strong component, that is the one with no exiting edges.